# What is the meaning of these terms in image processing?

Tags: terminology, image-processing

I'm a newbie in the Image Processing field, and I got many terms that sound weird to me. There are:

1. Moments
2. Local and global characteristic
3. Energy of Image
4. Color Temperature

What does each of them represent in an image?

Answer (score 6):

1. In image processing, computer vision and related fields, an [image moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment) is a certain particular weighted average (moment) of the image pixels' intensities, or a function of such moments, usually chosen to have some attractive property or interpretation.
2. Local and global characteristics. Example, suppose we want to smooth a noisy image. We could smooth the entire image based upon the noise or some other characteristic of the whole image, i.e., globally, or we could smooth the image based upon the noise and/or rate of change of events in sub-regions of that image, multiple local processing of the image. An example of local, or region by region, image proccessing is the [Pixon method](http://www.adass.org/adass/proceedings/adass98/puetterrc/).
3. Energy of image. This only appears in the context of entropy for image processing; it is the information content approach to understanding images. Answered [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562801/what-is-energy-in-image-processing).
4. Color temperature has more to do with the black body temperature illumination of an image than intrinsic color, [see link](http://www.photographymad.com/pages/view/what-is-colour-temperature).

Comment: Color Temperature would have to do with a display rather than an image. In general it refers to the display's white point.

Comment: @Wayne Indeed. For completely backlit images, you get the combination of both intrinsic image and its illumination or you see nothing.